# set authorization header from httponly cookie conditionally nginx

Tags: nginx, cookies, header, authorization, nginx-config

I want to set token in authorisation header from httponly cookie only in case when cookie named "access_token" is included in request.

there are two ways of making request in my app

1. token is passed in authorisation header
2. token is passed with httponly cookie

I want both to work, so I need to do something like this:

if cookie named "access_token" exists put it in authorisation header
and if it not exists do not modify authorisation header because it means token is already passed in authorisation header

I tried this:

```
 if ($cookie_access_token) {
     proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $cookie_access_token";
  }
```

but it does not work because I can not set header in IF block